# Excel VBA - hiding rows if other rows are hidden

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry, I have searched but have only found solutions similar to mine that I think should work! I have a button set up in a financial worksheet to hide rows that have value=0 in each of four colums. This is working fine except then I have a seperation row that I also want to hide if a subtotal row itself is hidden. It is hiding that row that I am having problems with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'macro hides rows if all four columns contain zero values

'declare and initialize variables
Dim Col1 As String        'stores the column letter for the first column to examine
    Col1 = "C"
Dim Col2 As String        'stores the column letter for the second column to examine
    Col2 = "D"
Dim Col3 As String        'stores the column letter for the third column to examine
    Col3 = "E"
Dim Col4 As String        'stores the column letter for the fourth column to examine
    Col4 = "F"
Dim ListBottom As String  'stores the cell reference of the column that is populated for each record
    ListBottom = "A65536"
Dim FirstRow As Long      'first row with data to inspect
    FirstRow = 3

'declare and initialize system variables
Dim LastRow As Long       'store the last row with data
    LastRow = 300 'Range(ListBottom).End(xlUp).Row   'moves up to the last row with data

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For x = FirstRow To LastRow
    If Cells(x, Col1).Value = "0" And Cells(x, Col2).Value = "0" And Cells(x, Col3).Value = "0" And Cells(x, Col4).Value = "0" Then
       Cells(x, Col1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

        'Expenses section tenant, utilites and maint - hides spacing and underlines if data rows are hidden'
        If Cells("C73").Value = 0 And Cells("D73").Value = 0 And Cells("E73").Value = 0 And Cells("F73").Value = 0 Then
            Rows("72").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        If Rows("82").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            Rows("81").EntireRow.Hidden = True And Rows("83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
     End If
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The top part hiding the 0 rows works fine, it is in the bottom section that I can't get to work. I have included the two different ways (starting in line 29) I have tried and neither one works.

If there is a more elegant way to do this, I am certainly open to it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't panic, the solution should be quite simple (and I'll try to provide some "elegance" to your code) :D

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' You don't need to Dim all those variables. Also they were constants not variables :)
' In case you need to declare a constant use "Const x As yourType = value"

Dim ListBottom As String  'stores the cell reference of the column that is populated for each record
Dim FirstRow As Long      'first row with data to inspect
Dim LastRow As Long       'store the last row with data

ListBottom = "A65536" ' You can address the last cell with some commands like .SpecialCells or .End. I strongly suggest googling them up ;)
FirstRow = 3
LastRow = 300  'moves up to the last row with data

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For x = FirstRow To LastRow
   If Cells(x, 3).Value = "0" And Cells(x, 4).Value = "0" And Cells(x, 5).Value = "0" _ 
     And Cells(x, 6).Value = "0" Then ' WARNING: "0" indicates a STRING in which 
     ' you find a Chr 0. When you (like below) say = 0 without the "", it means 
     ' that you're comparing to a NUMERIC value. In this case, it would do good 
     ' storing your values in some variables with a numeric type (Integer, Long, 
     ' Double) or a string and then compare them as fail-safe!

         Cells(x, 3).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        'Expenses section tenant, utilites and maint - hides spacing and underlines if data rows are hidden'
        If Cells("C73").Value = 0 And Cells("D73").Value = 0 And Cells("E73").Value = 0 And Cells("F73").Value = 0 Then
            Rows("72").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        If Rows("82").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            Rows("81").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' DANGER: for multiple commands you
            ' can't simply give "command" AND "command. All things that are between
            ' "Then" and "End If" are executed sequentially
            Rows("83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Didn't test it but should work. I recommend doing some test with those things I said back in the code, they could help you a lot in the future!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help (and tutelage!) I copied in your code and the 70's rows section kicked out a Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error. So I just tried pasting the 80's rows section over it and changed to the 70's references it worked perfectly. Thank you again for your solution and saving my morning!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'macro hides rows if all four columns contain zero values

'declare and initialize variables
Dim Col1 As String        'stores the column letter for the first column to examine
    Col1 = "C"
Dim Col2 As String        'stores the column letter for the second column to examine
    Col2 = "D"
Dim Col3 As String        'stores the column letter for the third column to examine
    Col3 = "E"
Dim Col4 As String        'stores the column letter for the fourth column to examine
    Col4 = "F"
Dim ListBottom As String  'stores the cell reference of the column that is populated for each record
    ListBottom = "A65536"
Dim FirstRow As Long      'first row with data to inspect
    FirstRow = 3

'declare and initialize system variables
Dim LastRow As Long       'store the last row with data
    LastRow = 300 'Range(ListBottom).End(xlUp).Row   'moves up to the last row with data

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For x = FirstRow To LastRow
    If Cells(x, Col1).Value = "0" And Cells(x, Col2).Value = "0" And Cells(x, Col3).Value = "0" And Cells(x, Col4).Value = "0" Then
       Cells(x, Col1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

       'Expenses section tenant, utilites and maint - hides spacing and underlines if data rows are hidden'
       Cells(x+1, Col1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Instead of veryfing if a row is hidden, hide the secondary row at the same time as you hide the main one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this didn't work for me. If I am following your code correctly, I don't want to hide every row after a hidden row, just a few specific ones. Thanks for your time though, I appreciate it!